# R plotrix radial.plot Remove Label Background

Tags: r, label, plotrix

I'm using radial.plot from the plotrix-package to make some radial plots. The scripts are working fine, but I dont like that the labels have a white background (the background is overlapping with the radial plot). Is there a way to remove the background of the labels? I did an online research and also had a look at the package documentation, but I didnt find the right command.

Thanks a lot!

Here's an example:

```
library(plotrix)
means <- c(5,3,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,2,1,2,2,5,6,7)  
mean.names <- c("Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label","Very Long Label") 
rada1 <- radial.plot(means, labels=mean.names,rp.type="p", radial.lim=c(1,7),line.col="firebrick1", lwd=3, start=0, radlab=FALSE,label.prop=1.1,show.grid.labels = 2)
```

This results in the following plot, where I have put yellow circles where the label background overlaps the radial plot:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added a script and a picture.